# Converting a Modal class component to a functional component with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mdbootstrap

i am trying to convert a Modal class component of [MDBootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/modals/basic/) into Functional component with hooks but it is not working as expected. when i click on the button,the modal appears but it doesn't disappers

here the class component

```
class ModalPage extends Component {
    state = {
        modal8: false
    }

    toggle = nr => () => {
        let modalNumber = 'modal' + nr
        this.setState({
            [modalNumber]: !this.state[modalNumber]
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <MDBContainer>
                <MDBIcon far icon="eye" onClick={this.toggle(8)}>

                </MDBIcon>
                <MDBModal isOpen={this.state.modal8} toggle={this.toggle(8)} fullHeight position="top">
                    <MDBModalHeader toggle={this.toggle(8)}>MDBModal title</MDBModalHeader>
                    <MDBModalBody>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
                        magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat.
                    </MDBModalBody>
                    <MDBModalFooter>
                        <MDBBtn color="secondary" onClick={this.toggle(8)}>Close</MDBBtn>
                        <MDBBtn color="primary">Save changes</MDBBtn>
                    </MDBModalFooter>
                </MDBModal>
            </MDBContainer>
        );
    }
}

export default ModalPage;
```

and what i've tried with hooks

```
const ModalPage = props => {
    const [modal8, setModal8] = useState(false);

    const toggle = nr => () => {
        let modalNumber = 'modal' + nr;
        setModal8({
            [modalNumber]: !modal8[modalNumber]
        });
    }
    return(
        <MDBContainer>
            <MDBIcon far icon="eye" onClick={toggle(8)}>

            </MDBIcon>
            <MDBModal isOpen={modal8} toggle={toggle(8)} fullHeight position="top">
                <MDBModalHeader toggle={toggle(8)}>MDBModal title</MDBModalHeader>
                <MDBModalBody>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                </MDBModalBody>
                <MDBModalFooter>
                    <MDBBtn color="secondary" onClick={toggle(8)}>Close</MDBBtn>
                    <MDBBtn color="primary">Save changes</MDBBtn>
                </MDBModalFooter>
            </MDBModal>
        </MDBContainer>
    )
}
export default ModalPage;
```

Comment: Try to update the state using `setModal8(!modal8)`

Comment: thank you, it works!

Comment: Not a problem ;) If I provide an answer will you `validate` and `upvote` it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `useState` hook like this:

```js
const [modal8, setModal8] = useState(false);
```

allow you to update your state like this:

```js
setModal8(true);
```

In your case, you want to toggle the value of `modal8`. You can easely achieve this using the not (`!`) operator like that:

```js
setModal8(!modal8);
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had to do `setModal8(!modal8)`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25700969)

Comment: @Andreas Actually this is the right answer. Explanation are maybe weak but the the problem is solved using this.